# Refreshing before presentmodalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

A press of a button invokes a view in my code:

```
buttonlabel.text = @"Wait";
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
buttonlabel.text = @"Done";
```

I want to change the label immediately to "Wait" after the button is clicked. What's happening currently is that the presentation of the view takes 1-2 secs, and the label changes to "Wait" only after those 1-2 secs have passed, and just before the view changes.

Changing the animation from YES to NO does not help.

Comment: are the three lines of code in an `IBAction`? Will the text change immediately if you comment out the `presentModalView` line?

Comment: The text does change immediately if I take out presentModalView line. The lines are not from IBAction (I am not using a NIB file). The button is created programatically. The lines of code are from the method that is invoked when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *queue* the presenting of the view controller so that the system has a chance to actually change the text of your button to "Wait". If you want more information, Google `runloop iOS`.

```
buttonlabel.text = @"Wait";
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
});
```

But you really should investigate why presenting the VC takes so much time and instead find a way to optimise your code. Search ways to incorporate concurrency and don't block the main thread.

Comment: posted my answer right after you, but yours is right too so I'll vote yours up

Comment: I expect the VC to take a couple of secs as I am doing some processing there. I tried the above but it does not help. In fact, it prevents the label from changing at all, for some reason. I should mention that my button is in a table row, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I was took quick to post my reply. Your solution did work. I had accidentally left the buttonlabel.text line after your code, that reset it to the initial value, and so I did not notice the change. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonlabel.text = @"Wait";

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
     buttonlabel.text = @"Done";

});
```

Comment: You don't really need to *delay* the task, just queuing it is sufficiently. ;-)

Comment: I tried this too but it does not help. In fact, it prevents the label from changing to "Wait" (or perhaps it happens too fast before switching to new VC), for some reason. I should mention that my button is in a table row, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I was took quick to post my reply. Your solution worked also. I had accidentally left the buttonlabel.text line after your code, that reset it to the initial value, and so I did not notice the change. Thank you for your help.